# How we add elastic search result(searchResponse) keys and value in a list where key is not duplicate

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How can we add elastic search result(searchResponse) keys and value in a list where we don't want duplicate key in a list? Because we want to return a list from our function.

```
      for (int i = 0; i < hits.totalHits(); i++) {      
                responseFields = (Map<String, Object>) hits.getAt(i).getSource();
                Student st=new Student();       
             Iterator it = responseFields.entrySet().iterator();
                 while (it.hasNext()) {
                     Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
//use list here
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue()+);
}}
```

In that case every time we get duplicate key for every for loop iteration.According to requirement i should save the result in a list with single  keys.which can make header in a table representation.

Comment: Do you use REST services or elastic's java api?

Comment: can you elaborate more on your requirements and actual response format? What should happen to the different values of the duplicate keys?

Answer (score 2):

A Set is pretty much just what you want. It's a list, that is special made to not allow duplicates (this is a gross oversimplification).

```
      Set uniqueValues = new HashSet<Entry>();
      for (int i = 0; i < hits.totalHits(); i++) {      
                responseFields = (Map<String, Object>) hits.getAt(i).getSource();
                Student st=new Student();       
             Iterator it = responseFields.entrySet().iterator();
                 while (it.hasNext()) {
                     Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    uniqueValues.add(pair);
//use list here

}}
```

This should work, but only if the pairs key and value both need to be unique.

EDIT: I just saw that you need to do something if you get duplicates. To do this you can just use the uniqueValues.contains() method. It will tell you if it's already in the set. so:

```
if(!uniqueValues.contains(pair))
     uniqueValues.add(pair)
else addToTableOrSomething
```

If you just want the keys to be unique you can use a Map. It allows you to do cointains() on just the key.

```
      Map uniqueValues = new HashMap<Something, Somthing>();
      for (int i = 0; i < hits.totalHits(); i++) {      
                responseFields = (Map<String, Object>) hits.getAt(i).getSource();
                Student st=new Student();       
             Iterator it = responseFields.entrySet().iterator();
                 while (it.hasNext()) {
                     Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    if(!uniqueeValues.contains(pair.getKey())
                       uniqueValues.put(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
                    else doSomthingElse

//use list here

}}
```